# Load external page HTML via javascript or flash or java

Tags: java, javascript, html, flash, load

I need to load somehow the html code of a webpage A into a javascript string of another webpage B, on a different host. I know this is impossible to do with javascript alone because of the same origin policy, and I know I could do it loading the page via php on my server and then send results back to the user's client but I wouldn't be able to handle so many requests, so I need it to be done directly by the user's browser. I can use nearly whatever browser scripting language/applet framework common enough to be installed on the majority of my users' computers, like flash and java.
On example, what if I use flash or java to load the external html code and then call a javascript callback function providing the source? Could this work?
Do you have ANY idea? I gratefully accept any suggestion, and I REALLY appreciate examples!

Thank you very much!
Matteo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would require a digitally signed and trusted applet in order to reach cross-domain, short of the user running a plug-in 2 architecture JRE and the site implementing a [Cross-Domain XML](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#CROSSDOMAINXML).

> Ordinarily, unsigned Java applets or applications may only connect
>   back to the web server from which they originated. This restriction
>   prevents an applet from causing denial-of-service attacks by making
>   rapid connections to arbitrary machines on the Internet.
>
> In Java SE 6 update 10, both the Java Web Start and Java Plug-In
>   technologies contain preliminary support for cross-domain policy
>   files, which specify how unsigned code may access web services on the
>   Internet. The crossdomain.xml policy file is hosted on a given server
>   and allows either selected clients, or clients from anywhere, to
>   connect to that server. Cross-domain policy files make accessing web
>   services much easier, particularly from unsigned applets.

Answer (score 1):

"via php on my server and then send results back to the user's client but I wouldn't be able to handle so many requests"

So many requests? That is not so many reqs; just making php script to read couple page and creating new page depending the data. If that is too much for your server ..hard to believe.. you sure can do that kind of thing with flash (clients computer) to load those two pages, and parse the datas to one html page and display it (via js) to clients browser. Kind of weird question after all.. perhaps i did not understand it :)